# React Native FlatList not working with object

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have data like this but my flat list is not working

```
Object {
  "error": false,
  "items": Array [
    Object {
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_item_id": 1,
      "item_description": "This is free product.",
      "item_img": "http//....",
      "item_name": "XPRS Chicken Burger",
      "item_points": 150,
    },
    Object {
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_item_id": 3,
      "item_description": "This is free product.",
      "item_img": "http//....",
      "item_name": "Chicken Chees Burger",
      "item_points": 550,
    },
    Object {
      "category_id": 1,
      "category_item_id": 4,
      "item_description": "This is free product.",
      "item_img": "http//....",
      "item_name": "Zinger Chees Burger",
      "item_points": 750,
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: You have to pass an array as `data` in `flatlist`

Answer (score 1):

```
const DATA = [
  {
    category_id: 1,
    category_item_id: 1,
    item_description: "This is free product.",
    item_img: "http//....",
    item_name: "XPRS Chicken Burger",
    item_points: 150,
  },

  {
    category_id: 1,
    category_item_id: 3,
    item_description: "This is free product.",
    item_img: "http//....",
    item_name: "Chicken Chees Burger",
    item_points: 550,
  },
];

const Item = ({ item_name }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{item_name}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => <Item title={item.item_name} />;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```